# What happens if I delete a Model class (.js) in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I recently started taking a course on Node JS and Mongo DB. During the course, I created a model class:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const IdeaSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    details: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
mongoose.model('ideas', IdeaSchema);
```

This created a 'table' (correct me if I'm wrong) in the MongoDB database, and editing the class changed the design of the table. So, what happens if I delete the class? Does the 'table' get deleted? Why? And if not, how can I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Mongoose starts with a Schema. Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection. It's just a blueprint of the house, deleting the Schema doesn't mean you are deleting the actual physical house or in mongoDB the collection.

You can change your schema anytime, without having any changes / effect on your old documents. You can still retrieve it and add new documents with new added fields based on the new modified schema.

To easily manage your mongoDb data, you can install tools like Robo3T see https://robomongo.org If you are new in mongo, this kind of tools will save you time and help you manage your dbs and collections easily. Everytime you change / add new schemas, you can use the tool to delete db, delete collections, insert documents, etc.

Or if you are just accessing mongo via terminal, this mongo shell commands will help you https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/mongodb/118/mongodb-cheatsheat.html

For more details on mongoose schema, see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 1):

your table didn't get deleted. just your schema changed and added your new field in same table.

Comment: So if I already added records before deleting the schema, can they be retrieved?